# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

how to solve this issue: `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast`? Now I am trying to do somethin like that:

```
  ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
 BasesService().SelectBaseAsync(
  basesNames?[index]['id]);
},
```

Also I was trying to cast to needed type like this -   `basesNames?[index]['id'] as List<int>` ,  but it also returned me the same error: `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast`

the print of basesNames - `[{name: MyDb, id: 4}]`

```
Future<bool> SelectBaseAsync(List<int> integers) async {
   

    final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          'http:mysecurelink'
        )
        .build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    bool select = false;
    List<int>? saveInts;
    if (hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await hubConnection
          .invoke('SelectBaseAsync', args: [integers]).then((value) {
        saveInts = integers;
        select = value as bool;
      });
    }

    hubConnection.onclose(({error}) {
      throw Exception(error);
    });
    print(saveInts);
    print(select);
    return select;
  }
```

Comment: are you sure the error happened for this line?

Comment: could you include the result of print(basesNames);?

Comment: @eamirho3ein print returns me  [{name: MyDb, id: 4}]

Comment: thanks, could you include BasesService().SelectBaseAsync code too?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I also added this method. Backend-devs says I should send List<int> to this method but is us still only one id's db

Comment: @inkwelll075 so you should use second approach I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in `print(basesNames)` result, basesNames[index]['id'] return an `int` value not `list of int`, so what you can do are either change your `SelectBaseAsync` constructer to accept an int instead of `List<int>` or pass value like this:

```
BasesService().SelectBaseAsync([basesNames?[index]['id']]);
```

Comment: oh, I was so sured I should ask about this issue backend devs first. Thank you, I understood what is going on